# How to filter no data value with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, numpy, nodata

I have a Tiff file that has no data value = -3.40282347e+38. I want to filter no data and get raw values with gdal. I tried with below code:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array

dataset = gdal.Open("path/to/file.tif")
array = dataset.ReadAsArray()

lst = []
for v in array:
    if v < 0:
        lst.append(v)

print lst
```

but I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3B0d5H.py", line 10, in <module>
    if v < 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it needs a double loop.

Comment: Alternatively, you could strip the nodata cells from your raster prior to going into the array for analysis - it's not clear if you want to keep the nodata cells for analysis, or just remove them.  Gdalwarp could do this easily.A simple os.system command could accomplish this:

    os.system('gdalwarp -srcnodata "value [-3.40282347e+38]" -dstnodata "value []" input.tif output.tif')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to filter **no data** and get **raw values** you need following code:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array

dataset = gdal.Open("path/to/file.tif")
array = dataset.ReadAsArray()

lst = [ element for v in array for element in v if element > 0 ]

print lst
```

I tried it out with a raster with no data values equal to -999 and it works adequately.

**Editing Note:**

Based in your commentary, you don't need to filter these values. It's necessary to change **no data** values to **NaN** values for calculating directly **np.nanpercentiles**. Following code calculates this (percentile 50) for my raster with -999 **no data** values.

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array

dataset = gdal.Open("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_raster_nodata.tif")
array = dataset.ReadAsArray()

nan_array = array

nan_array[array == -999] = np.nan

print np.nanpercentile(nan_array, 50)
```

Result is 6.

Comment: Hi @xunilk, Is it possible to use `block` in your code for faster run in large raster files?

Comment: What do you want to do with data array?

Comment: I want to compute quantile (percentile) without negative values (i.e. nodata values).

Comment: I posted new question for my work. (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260019/how-to-reclassify-a-raster-based-on-quantile-and-without-no-data-in-qgis)

Comment: See my **Editing Note**. You have the answer.