# How to reclassify a raster based on quantile and without no data in QGIS3?

Tags: qgis

Revisiting this topic, I managed to use the answer given by https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/45066/xunilk in version 2.18, but this code does not run in version QGis 3.16, as shown below:

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterField
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination
import processing

from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureSink
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array, osr

@alg("rastertoquantiles", "Raster to quantiles", group="rastertools", group_label="Raster tools")
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name="INPUT", label="Input raster")
@alg.input(type=alg.SINK, name="OUTPUT", label="Output raster")

dataset = gdal.Open('F:\QGis3_Plugins\Tutorials about Python Programming\CartaPerigo_01.tif')
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()
array = dataset.ReadAsArray()

new_array = array
nan_array = array

nan_array[array == nodata] = np.nan

percentile_80 = np.nanpercentile(nan_array, 80)
percentile_60 = np.nanpercentile(nan_array, 60)
percentile_40 = np.nanpercentile(nan_array, 40)
percentile_20 = np.nanpercentile(nan_array, 20)
percentile_0 = np.nanpercentile(nan_array, 0)

for i, v in enumerate(new_array):
for j, element in enumerate(v):
if element <= percentile_0:
new_array[i,j] = 1
if element > percentile_0 and element <= percentile_20:
new_array[i,j] = 2
if element > percentile_20 and element <= percentile_40:
new_array[i,j] = 3
if element > percentile_40 and element <= percentile_60:
new_array[i,j] = 4
if element > percentile_60 and element <= percentile_80:
new_array[i,j] = 5
if element > percentile_80:
new_array[i,j] = 6

new_array[ new_array != new_array ] = nodata

geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
wkt = dataset.GetProjection()

## Create gtif file

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
output_file = 'F:\QGis3_Plugins\Tutorials about Python Programming\CartaPerigo_01_Quant.tif'

dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file,
band.XSize,
band.YSize,
1,
gdal.GDT_Int16)

#writting output raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( new_array )
#setting nodata value
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(nodata)
#setting extension of output raster

## top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution

dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

## setting spatial reference of output raster

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
#Close output raster dataset

dataset = None
dst_ds = None

Comment: Forget to say that the original posting can accessed at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260019/how-to-reclassify-a-raster-based-on-quantile-and-without-no-data-in-qgis

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks